# How to iterate through limited set of instance properties?

Tags: c#, linq, class, foreach

I have a class with huge number of properties but I want to alter only several of them. Could you suggest me how to implement functionality below:

```
var model = session.Load<MyType>(id);

foreach(var property in [model.RegistrationAddress, model.ResidenceAddress, model.EmploymentAddress, model.CorrespondenceAddress])
{
    // alter each of the given properties...
}
```

Comment: This seems like linqAbuse and any reflection solution would just be inefficient.. whats wrong with just updating multiple properties in as  normal?

Comment: If one follows normal update way, then one has to make a function that alters a property, and then call that function several times with different input parameters. I am wondering if it is possible to iterate only through limited set of properties to be altered.

Comment: Make a method that takes in a model and only edits those properties you require to be changed... Your hard coding these parameters anyway so I presume theres an exact use involved here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When wrapping it in an `object[]` you can get all values, but you loose the knowledge of the property behind it.

```
foreach( var property in
            new object[]
            { model.RegistrationAddress
            , model.ResidenceAddress
            , model.EmploymentAddress
            , model.CorrespondenceAddress
            }
       )
{
    // alter each of the given properties...
}
```

You can use a `Dictionary` instead:

When wrapping it in an `object[]` you can get all values, but you loose the knowledge of the property behind it.

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, object> property in 
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            { { "RegistrationAddress", model.RegistrationAddress}
            , { "ResidenceAddress", model.ResidenceAddress } ...
            }
        )
{
    // alter each of the given properties...
}
```

Ideally, in the next version of c#, you can use `nameof`:

```
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            { { nameof(RegistrationAddress), model.RegistrationAddress}
            , { nameof(ResidenceAddress), model.ResidenceAddress } ...
            }
```

When you need to set the parameters, you can use something like this:

```
public class GetSet<T>
{
    public GetSet(Func<T> get, Action<T> set)
    {
        this.Get = get;
        this.Set = set;
    }

    public Func<T> Get { get; set; }

    public Action<T> Set { get; set; }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
ClassX x = new ClassX();

foreach (var p in new GetSet<string>[] { new GetSet<string>(() => { return x.ParameterX; }, o => { x.ParameterX = o; }) })
{
    string s = p.Get();

    p.Set("abc");
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to change the property in this way. If you try to compile a full sample you'd get `Cannot assign to 'property' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'` compile time error. One will have to use ugly reflection to achieve this.

Comment: @oleksii: You are right. Next idea. A few seconds please.

Comment: @oleksii: It took a few minutes. Check!

Comment: @PatrickHofman This looks so much better than what I would have written :D. Being lazy, I would just set each property in code, w/o using loops and reflection (I know it's not *cool*).